# How to pass extra_context to auth_views.password_change in URL handler

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I have a URL handler for changing passwords, such as this:

```
                       url(r'^password/change/$',
                           auth_views.password_change,
                           {'template_name' : 'account/password/password_change_form.html'},
                           name='auth_password_change'),
```

All is good, and my template is loaded, and password changing works as expected. However, my template needs to access `request.user`. The `request` object is not passed by default to the template from the built-in the `auth_views.password_change` view.

I know that the `auth_views.password_change` view can be passed in extra context, which it will pass along to the template. I just do not know how to do it in my URL handler.

I know that I could just write another view which wraps around `auth_views.password_change`, but I am curious if there is a shortcut way to do it from within the URL handler.

Can you show me how to modify my current URL handler to pass in the current `request` object as `extra_context` to the `auth_views.password_change` view?

Comment: I -- too -- am in search of an example. (I'm using v0.7)  After reading the docs and looking at the code, it seems that one would add 'extra_context' in the dictionary passed to the url() call, buried in registration.urls.  If I'm not supposed to modify the distributed source code to do the above, it seems I'm only left with the graft in my own urls.py: (r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')).  But how do I pass in "extra_context" there?  Does "include()" have a syntax to do this?  I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you do that in the urlconf - but you can't pass `request.user` in extra_context, because the urls.py has no access to the request.

But `password_change`, like all built-in views, uses `RequestContext` to render the template - which means that there is a `user` object there automatically (passed in by `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth`, unless you've removed it from the `CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` list in settings.py).